# How to find out maximum value from the result set of join of two tables

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables

In employee table there is employee information like below :

```
+-------+-----------+----------------+
| Empid | FirstName | empterritories |
+-------+-----------+----------------+
|     1 | Jhon      | North Amercia  |
|     2 | Steve     | Asia           |
+-------+-----------+----------------+
```

And Orders table to store order information related to orders

```
+----------+-------+-------------+
| Order_id | Empid |   Adress    |
+----------+-------+-------------+
|        1 |     2 | xyz city    |
|        2 |     3 | ert country |
+----------+-------+-------------+
```

I join these two tables to get the number of orders booked by each employee in the following query;

```
 SELECT employees.FirstName , employees.id , COUNT(orders.OrderID) FROM orders JOIN
 employees ON orders.EmployeeID=employees.EmployeeID GROUP BY
 employees.FirstName
```

Now i want to write query to find out the employee who has booked the maximum orders along with the no of orders? But not able to find the correct expression/ order.
A quick fix will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose that your query not correct: `GROUP BY employees.FirstName, employees.id` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 employees.FirstName , employees.id , COUNT(orders.OrderID) 
FROM orders 
JOIN employees ON orders.EmployeeID=employees.EmployeeID 
ORDER BY COUNT(orders.OrderID) DESC
GROUP BY employees.FirstName
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your help you gave me the direction to move just some modifications to your query as TOP does not work in mysql so added LIMIT clause and it worked .

SELECT  employees.FirstName  ,employees.id, COUNT(orders.OrderID) AS TOTAL_ORDERS FROM orders 
JOIN employees ON orders.EmployeeID=employees.EmployeeID GROUP BY employees.FirstName ORDER BY TOTAL_ORDERS DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer:

```
WITH (
SELECT employees.FirstName , employees.id , COUNT(orders.OrderID) as orders_qty 
    FROM orders JOIN employees ON orders.EmployeeID=employees.EmployeeID 
    GROUP BY employees.FirstName, employees.id
) AS T
SELECT TOP 1 FirstName, id, orders_qty
FROM T
```

not sure about MySQL.